# JQuery click() not fired in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, click

I'm not a javascript professional so I can't solve the following code alone.

I have a delegate function which works fine in IE7. The Problem in IE8 I figuered out is the last jquery-function click(). Does anybody know how I can solve this for IE 8

thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LightboxDelegate(url,caption)
{
$('#impressionen').attr({
href: url,
title: caption,
alt: caption
});
$('#impressionen').lightBox();
$('#impressionen').click();

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure whether this helps or not. But try replacing

```
$('#impressionen').click();
```

with

```
$('#impressionen').trigger('click');
```

See

[trigger](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger)

> Trigger an event on every matched
>   element.

Comment: Thanks a lot - with trigger it works fine, but now there is a new Problem in ie8. It seams the the attr()-function also not works. The lightbox apears, but it displays loading all the time.

Anybody got a new idea?

And thank you all for the rapid help

Comment: Are you sure that lightbox doesn't override some behaviors like clicking?

Comment: Is it possible that MS has somehow hotfixed your solution, it does not seem to be working for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

What is subscribed to that click event?

I would expect the following to work:

```
//set up event
$('#impressionen').click(function() { 
    alert('it works!');
});

//alert should show in all browsers
$('#impressionen').click();
```

However this is a simple example - there are other things that can break this. How are you setting up the click event?