# jQuery Click binding does not fire in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

The jQuery click binding is never fired in IE8 (works in IE9, Chrome, etc.)  How can I get the click event to fire in IE8, and why is it not currently?

Note:  I've tried changing the href to '#', but that is not working either.

```
$('<a/>', {
    id: 'anchor-id',
    href: 'javascript:void(0);',
    'class': 'button-next',
    html: 'HTML'
}).click(function() {
     alert('clicked');
}).appendTo($('#append'));​
```

version: 1.7.2

Comment: what version of jquery are you using

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906892/jquery-click-not-fired-in-ie8

Comment: most liekly it has something to do with binding the click before appending it. Use the document binding so it will pick up the click for sure, see my answer

Comment: works perfectly fine for me in IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/zLG85/  IE 8.0.6001.18702

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

`.on()` will create an event handler for all current and future elements that match your selector. In the statement below the `click` event will be handled for all elements with a class of `button-next` regardless of when they are added to the DOM.

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-next', function(e) 
{ 
  //do something
});
```

Comment: +1 for `on` to bind it. I used `$('.some-element-class')` instead of `$(document)` to get "closer" to the element, instead of searching the whole dom. Still had to be sure to choose an element that IE8 knew was there.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-next', function() {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work in IE8 using the following:

```
<div id="append"></div>
<script>
    var aLink = $('<a/>', { id: 'anchor-id', href: '#',html : 'click me'}).on('click', function () {
         alert('clicked');
    });
    $('#append').append(aLink);


</script>
```

Also, make sure you do not have any console.log()'s in there. IE does not like them very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stopped event propagation?

Typically with links you have to do something like:

```
<a href="#">HTML</a>
```

This script would work:

```
jQuery('#someLink').bind('click', function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();  
  //.. do something  
});
```

*NOTE:* your javascript:void(); **SHOULD** have covered this, but just checking.

If it's not a "real" link, you're not forced to use the `A` element, as you can simulate hover events with the same jQuery that creates the object:

```
jQuery("<span>", {  
  text: "html",  
  id: "anchor-id",  
  "class": "button-next",  
  click: function() { /* do something */ },  
  mouseover: function() { /* hover over */ },  
  mouseout: function() { /* hover out */ }
}).appendTo(jQuery('#append'));
```